# Docker initializing volume exiting container

Tags: docker, volumes

I am running scripts from:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/docker/docker_storage.htm > **Data Volumes**

When I want to perform such script:

```
docker run -d -v /home/docker/demo:/nexus-data --name="volume" sonatype/nexus3
```

I see on container list that **volume** container is **Up** and **running** but after few seconds it state change to **Exited**, why?

Comment: `docker logs` might tell you something about why the main container’s process exited.  Leaving off the `-d` option will run the container in the foreground, which might be more convenient if it’s exiting immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A docker container exits when the main process finishes. For example if you execute a command that will generate some output - it will execute it (depend of settings save it) and exit.

Comment: So what is difference between given script and "docker run -d --name="volume" sonatype/nexus3" (which is not exiting) in this situation with main process?

Comment: The reason it is exiting in the first case is permissions - it tries to create the dir /nexus-data (you can change it to /home/nexus-data and it is fine). That is why in first case container exits with fail and second is ok. Regards (Sorry for the delay).

Answer (score 1):

You could try to see the live logs of the Docker container with the following command (basically, remove `-d` and add `-it`):

`docker run -it -v /home/docker/demo:/nexus-data --name="volume" sonatype/nexus3`

And try to pin points the exact issue.